# jquery validation function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I use the following function for stop allowing text and special characters in textbox. But if I copy the text like "aa2ss". It will allow as it is. If i copy paste means i don't want to allow the text, special characters from the string only allow numeric from string in this textbox. How can I do this?

```
      $("input[name$='inputid']").bind('keypress keyup',
          function(){
              $(this).val($(this).val.replace(/[^0-9]+$/i,''));
          }
      );
```

Comment: Hold on... So your work around is to simply strip everything that isn't a number - wouldn't you then just have completely meaningless data? Why not validate that it's numeric - if not, then raise an error back to the user?

Comment: this is happening because you are using keypress.This will take only keypresses.Try using onblur in the text input and then write the the above function inside the onblur

Comment: you can use the [input}(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) event also

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your function to the [jquery.blur() event](https://api.jquery.com/blur/):

```
  $("input[name$='inputid']").blur(function(){
      $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]+$/i,''));
  });
```

Comment: @User - try fixing the typo "val.replace" should be "val().replace"

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't the same logic to be run whenever user is pasting (instead of typing) texts into your input element, you just need to add the `paste` event to your existing event handler.

But first, you have a bit of typo:

```
...$(this).val.replace...
```

should be:

```
...$(this).val().replace...
```

And you also need to change your `regex` to catch the non-numeric characters not positioned at the end of the string from:

```
/[^0-9]+$/i
```

to:

```
/[^0-9]+/i .
```

Therefore the final code should be:

```
$("input[name$='inputid']").bind('keypress keyup paste',function(){  
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]+/i,''));
});
```

The jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hjehR/